# How to cover two different scenarios in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, case, where-clause

I have a stored procedure that has only one parameter `@tag nvarchar(100) = ''` .

So far my `WHERE` clause for the `SELECT` here was just `WHERE F.tag = @tag`.

This works as intended and returns all records where tag (i.e. a keyword) matches exactly the input parameter.

Is there a way that I can only apply this Where clause if the input parameter is NOT empty / '' and if it is then return all records ?

I cannot use `LIKE` here as in case of matches I only need exact match so I am looking for any way to cover both scenarios in one Select, so either check for matches if a tag is provided and otherwise return all records.

Can someone tell me how this could be done, e.g. by using `CASE` etc. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE @tag = '' OR F.tag = @tag
```

Comment: This is great and works perfect - didn't expect such an easy solution. :) Thanks a lot ! Will accept as soon as I can.

Comment: I'd recommend using `WHERE (@tag IS NULL OR @tag = '' OR F.tag = @tag)` - you also should check for `IS NULL`, and you should put these three conditions into brackets to avoid trouble with other conditions in your `WHERE` clause

Comment: well, the default is empty string. that is why i did not mention null

Comment: Yes, that was my thought as well. I think in my case NULL does not need to be covered but good to know in general.